# Can a database store two options in one cell?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm working on a database for a website, and at the moment, a duplicate entry is being made for every category that an item is listed under.

For instance, an entry for one item that has two categories looks like the following:

> PRODUCT ID: 1
>
> CATEGORY: 2
>
> NAME: Ethernet Cable
>
> PRODUCT ID: 1
>
> CATEGORY: 5
>
> NAME: Ethernet Cable

Am I wrong in assuming that this is inefficient? How would I store two options in one category, and should I?

Comment: If you talk about normalization, this is not inefficient, but the normal way to do it. So I would create 2 tables, one for Products and one for Categories, with 1-n relationship, so the Key of Product must be present also in Categories

Comment: Two tables, 1 for `Product` with columns `product_id | Name` and another for `Product Categories` with columns `product_id | category_id`. A third table if you want to store things about the `Category` with columns `category_id | name | etc...` Don't think about "Efficient" so much as disk space, but rather read and write. When retrieving the name of a product you want to get a single record back with the name. With a single table holding multiple records for each product you will get back multiple records all with the same name. That is inefficient.

Comment: Lastly, avoid storing more than one value in a single field. If you want to select "Products that are in category 5, but not also in category 3` you are going to have a bad time, your database is going to be crazy slow (you can't index multiple values in the same field). If you want to "Remove category 2 from all products` you are going to want to cry. Properly normalize your data. So you can rely on indexing for speed and joins for bringing your `1:n` data together.

Comment: @JNevill that makes a lot of sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make a pivot table and store the relation there

Category Table

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|     id              | category_name    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      5              |   Something name |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      2              |  Something name1 |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Product Table

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|     id              |  product_name    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      1              |Something product |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Category and product Table

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|     product_id      |  category_  id   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      1              |          2       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      1              |          5       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```